# Rails Controller respond_to return 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a bunch of controllers in my rails app that return :html format. When I try to access the url using .js extension it returns Completed 406 Not Acceptable. Shouldn't the correct behaviour is to return 404?

Thanks

Comment: no. The controller does not respond to javascript requests, so the request is not acceptable.

Comment: If I decides not to use respond_to block in my controller, and visit the url using .js extension, it returns the html views without the layout tempate.

Comment: 406 is exactly the right thing to return why no matching format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would get a `404` error if your controller's action was able to respond to the JS request but the `action.js.erb` did not exist. Since your controller only allows a response to `HTML`, the `406 Not Acceptable` error would be expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle JS requests, you'll have to have something like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js   
    format.html 
end
```

This will load the corresponding .js.erb or .html.erb files when that action is called. More information is available on the [Rails API](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to)